# If you put your hand in water while sleeping/drunk, will you pee yourself?

Tags: water, sleep, physiology

This is like an urban myth and a classic prank, but I never saw it in action.

Supposedly if someone is passed out or sleeping, the contact with water **will make him pee**. Is this true? If true, why does this happen?

Comment: [Busted](http://dsc.discovery.com/fansites/mythbusters/db/human-body/hand-water-asleep-urinate.html) by the __MythBusters__.

Comment: I wanted to try this at camp this summer.  MythBusters, while I love them, spoil some fun things.

Comment: @Oliver_C, so a sample of *two* people is sufficient to bust a myth? Had they peeed before sleeping?

Comment: [Here is the mythbusters extract of that episode](http://dsc.discovery.com/fansites/mythbusters/db/human-body/hand-water-asleep-urinate.html). As @Oliver_C said, I guess that the sample of two people isn't enough...

Comment: Andres, you do realize you just gave the same link from Oliver_C, right?

Comment: @Benjol - It depends on how the myth is formulated. The claim `something WILL happen` is not the same as `something CAN happen`.

Comment: @Benjol: IIRC the myth they wanted to bust was that it kind of always works, which wasn't the case.

Comment: @Cawas lol, sorry, didn't saw the link!

Comment: @Oliver_C, @Martin, it worked for Greg House :)

Comment: I would think this myth exists because there is no way not to wake a sober person when placing his hand in water.  A drunk person, so drunk as to not notice, is much more likely to piss himself.

Comment: It might not work on everybody, but I have seen it work on one person (a completely sober twelve year old).

Comment: I'm so sad this is still satisfactorily unanswered! :(

Answer (score 7):

OK, I'm gonna try a few links on you, not sure how "approved" they will be:

From [The Straight Dope](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/639/why-does-putting-someones-hand-in-warm-water-make-them-go-to-the-bathroom)

> The effectiveness of the stunt is a
>   matter of debate. Some urologists
>   scoff at the idea. But other medical
>   types have been known to tell patients
>   having a tough time urinating after
>   rectal surgery to put their hands in
>   warm water.

Wry extract from a pretty useless forum thread on [The Naked Science Foundation](http://www.thenakedscientists.com/forum/index.php?topic=18867):

> Short answer no with a but..
>
> long answer yes with an if...

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urination#Voluntary_control) says (but the cite is a dead link):

> The mechanism is unclear. The
>   phenomenon (...) of immersing the hand
>   of a sleeping person in water to make
>   this victim urinate in sleep, although
>   the efficacy of the trick is disputed.